# online Crm 2011 Dialog Workflow Issue - Response Type

Tags: dialog, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to create a new Proccess with Dialog (new Feature in Crm 5.0) which calls a CRM Query, returns a list of Customers, and after selecting the customers we want to use, I call a plugin which then prints the invoices for the Selected Customers. The plugin is programmed and working and also the dialog is created and the entire solution is working perfectly. But only for one Customer :(.

And this is the Issue. When you create a CRM Query in Online Crm 2011, you get 4 options as Response Type:
1.Single Line ( Text Box), 
2.List of Options ( Radio Buttons), where only one can be selected, 
3.Picklist (DropDown), where also only one item can be selected and 
4.Multiline ( Multiline TextBox)

And in my case none of these is not working, because I cannot select more Customers from these Response Types. It works only for one Customer :(

How to solve this issue? What are the options here, maybe a custom User Interface for the Dialog, or what? 
**What I need is a List of Checkboxes with the Customer Name, and then I can select more then one Customer for the invoicing proccess.**

Do I need to take another route in order to achieve this, or will the Dialogs do the job? Or can I create a Custom Response type which renders multiple selectable Checkboxes? **If yes, then how can I create a Custom Response Type?**

Any suggestion would be apreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Dialog feature will do what you need (checkbox list selection).  Another option would be to add a button on the ribbon, perhaps called Create Invoices, that launches a pop-up window (custom HTML web resource). This pop-up window could simply ask "Are you sure?" or it could even include some custom parameters for the Invoice generation.  Upon confirmation, it would use some JavaScript to talk to the ODATA endpoint to update a flag on each of these Customer records that would fire your plugin.

This way, a user could browse to a list of Customers, use the built-in checkbox to check off as many as they like, then click the Create Invoices button.

If you are good with HTML and JavaScript, probably the hardest part of this will be learning how to add a new Ribbon button.  It isn't the easiest to learn, but there are plenty of resources out there to help.

Comment: I agree.  The dialog feature is cool, but limited.  We tried to shoe horn it into several of our customizations only to end up falling back to custom web resources.

Comment: Thanks for the infos. I will probably do it with Html/JavaScript and a Ribbon Button. But REgarding Dialogs and Response Types, is there a posibility or a way to extend that part of the dialog?

Comment: There isn't a supported method to extend Dialogs that I've seen.  I believe you can use custom workflow activities in Dialogs, but you can't change the actual UI of the Dialog to add things like checkbox lists.